# Match array elements of the same index in SQL / BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, indexing, google-bigquery, matching

I want to output an element inside an array that match the index during a prior match in SQL/BigQuery

For example, I have these 5 fields. Match_Home_Date and Match_Away_date are in Array(String) format.

| Match_ID | Match_Home | Match_Away | Match_Home_Date | Match_Away_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 101, 102 | 103, 121 | [01-02-2021, 01-05-2021] | [01-07-2021, 01-09-2021] |
| 131 | 131, 140 | 117, 115 | [02-02-2021, 02-15-2021] | [02-20-2021, 02-25-2021] |

I want to output a "Final Date" field in which when the Match_ID matches to either Match_Home or Match_Away, it will output the corresponding Match_Home_Date or Match_Away_Date of the same index.

Output should be:

```
Final Date
01-09-2021
02-02-2021
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select Match_ID, 
  (Match_Home_Date || Match_Away_Date)[offset(
  ( select offset
    from unnest(split(Match_Home) || split(Match_Away)) id with offset 
    where trim(id)  = '' || Match_ID
  ))] as Final_Date
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

You can use below cte to test above

```
with your_table as (
  select 121 Match_ID, '101, 102' Match_Home, '103, 121' Match_Away, ['01-02-2021', '01-05-2021'] Match_Home_Date, ['01-07-2021', '01-09-2021'] Match_Away_Date union all
  select 131, '131, 140', '117, 115', ['02-02-2021', '02-15-2021'], ['02-20-2021', '02-25-2021'] 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried it with your sample data and it works.

But I tried it with my data, it didn't because maybe all my columns are STRING (my original data set are STRING, I just simplified for the question here). Match_ID, Match_Home, Match_Away are STRING, Match_Home_Date and Match_Away_Date are ARRAY (STRING)

Comment: If all your columns are string  - Just simply add `SPLIT` in second line - like `split(Match_Home_Date) || split(Match_Away_Date)`   - please try now and let me know!

Comment: Hi Mikhail, it still doesn't work bec the data in second line (Match_Home_Date and Match_Away_Date) are ARRAY<STRING> data. I think SPLIT only works for STRING right?

Comment: that's right! split works with string! have you tried with sample data in my answer? that sample data is based on how you described your data in your question! so obviously - if your real data is different - you should do respective adjustments!

Comment: Actually, yes it did seem my example was too simplistic? Here is my actual data.

MATCH_ID (STRING) | MATCH_HOME (STRING) | MATCH_AWAY (STRING) | MATCH_HOME_DATE (ARRAY<STRING>) | MATCH_AWAY_DATE (ARRAY<STRING>)

19.56V.25 |  19.56V.25, 19.52X.26 | 19.48W.27, 19.35R.28 | [2021-10-30,2021-10-31] | [2021-11-05,2021-11-06]

Final Date should be: 2021-10-30

Comment: Will do Mikhail, thanks for the help!