# SQL/BigQuery: Output data that match STRING array elements of same index

Tags: sql, arrays, indexing, google-bigquery, match

I want to output an element inside an array that match the index during a prior match in SQL/BigQuery

The objective is to match the MATCH_ID to either MATCH_HOME or MATCH_AWAY, then output the date (as MATCH_DATE) from MATCH_HOME_DATE (if it matches an element in MATCH_HOME) or MATCH_AWAY_DATE (if it matches an element in MATCH_AWAY). The matching date should have the same index with where it matched in MATCH_HOME or MATCH_DATE

For example, I have these 5 fields *(and their data types)*.

| MATCH_ID *(STRING)* | MATCH_HOME *(STRING)* | MATCH_AWAY *(STRING)* | MATCH_HOME_DATE *(ARRAY(STRING))* | MATCH_AWAY_DATE *(ARRAY(STRING))* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19.56V.25 | 19.56V.25, 19.52X.26 | 19.48W.27, 19.35R.28 | [2021-10-30,2021-10-31] | [2021-11-05,2021-11-06] |
| 19.24C.17 | 19.25S.19, 19.15M.17 | 19.21A.19, 19.24C.17 | [2021-11-27,2021-11-28] | [2021-12-11,2021-12-12] |

Output MATCH_DATE should be:

```
|MATCH_DATE |
|:---- |
| 2021-10-30 |
| 2021-12-12 |
```

Since line 1 matches with 1st element of MATCH_HOME and line 2 matches with 2nd element of MATCH_AWAY.

Comment: isn't it similar question to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105670/match-array-elements-of-the-same-index-in-sql-bigquery that you asked ?

Comment: I think it is EXACTLY SAME question and solution provided there works perfectly here! Can you explain please what is the difference here!!

Comment: Hi! The main difference is that the data I provided in the first post was too simplistic and not emphasizing the real type of data I am dealing with. i am having difficulty dealing with STRING and ARRAY(STRING) datasets so I am indicating it in this question.

Answer (score -1):

Need to convert strings into array. Then `JOIN` `UNNEST`ed arrays by indexes.

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT
    '19.56V.25' MATCH_ID,
    '19.56V.25, 19.52X.26' MATCH_HOME,
    '19.48W.27, 19.35R.28' MATCH_AWAY,
    ['2021-10-30',
    '2021-10-31'] MATCH_HOME_DATE,
    ['2021-11-05',
    '2021-11-06'] MATCH_AWAY_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    '19.24C.17',
    '19.25S.19, 19.15M.17',
    '19.21A.19, 19.24C.17',
    ['2021-11-27',
    '2021-11-28'],
    ['2021-12-11',
    '2021-12-12']
)
SELECT MATCH_ID, arr_1 MATCH_HOME, arr_2 MATCH_AWAY, MATCH_HOME_DATE, MATCH_AWAY_DATE FROM (
    SELECT * , 
    SPLIT(MATCH_HOME, ', ') MATCH_HOME_arr, 
    SPLIT(MATCH_AWAY, ', ') MATCH_AWAY_arr 
    FROM t
)
JOIN UNNEST(MATCH_HOME_arr) arr_1 WITH OFFSET 
JOIN UNNEST(MATCH_AWAY_arr) arr_2 WITH OFFSET USING (OFFSET)
JOIN UNNEST(MATCH_HOME_DATE) MATCH_HOME_DATE WITH OFFSET USING (OFFSET)
JOIN UNNEST(MATCH_AWAY_DATE) MATCH_AWAY_DATE WITH OFFSET USING (OFFSET)
```

Comment: Hi Timo, it looks like it's very different from what I would like to do. i wanted to do some matching, without breaking down data sets (as much as possible).